# Sending a buffer to the client to download

Tags: node.js, express, dropbox-api

I have a Buffer download on my Node.js server from Dropbox. I'd like to send that buffer (or convert it to a file and send it) to the client, and have it immediately begin downloading on the client side. What am I missing here?

```
var client = DBoxApp.client(req.session.dbox_access_token);

client.get(req.body.id, function(status, data, metadata) {
    // WHAT DO I DO HERE?
})
```

here's my angular (uses a promise). when I console.log(response I get an object that includes the buffer).

```
function(id, cloud){
  return $http.post('/download/'+cloud, {id: id}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
  }, function(response) {
    return $q.reject(response.data);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `dbox` module you're using has a `stream()` option which is probably better suited for file downloads. You should also make a call to `metadata` to look up the file's mime type. For example:

```
var middleware = function(req, res, next) {
    var client = DBoxApp.client(req.session.dbox_access_token);
    var file = req.body.id;

    client.metadata(file, function(status, reply) {
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + file);
        res.setHeader('Content-type', reply.mime_type);
        client
            .stream(file)
            .pipe(res)
            .on('error', next);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! So I get this data back to the client from an http get request. so now it's part of the response object as a buffer on the client. How can I have that buffer automatically be downloaded as a file once it gets back to the client?

Comment: To have the browser do a file download you set the `Content-disposition` and `Content-type` headers like I'm doing in my sample above. And it doesn't happen "once it gets back to the client", your node service is streaming the file from S3 to the browser chunk by chunk. Try running the code.

Comment: let me update my question with my full client and server code. it's not quite working still,

Comment: Updated my code, and used your code verbatim. this is what I got back when I console.log(response) 
���)`�1F1��KI;�B|��(�Ojr�<+�?д�l���:*av7��u
���*�1^]�T��-��9`g�����[L�o�F}���@~�M� �-F~�U0�[�3��B��Đ���zA��
3�'FDh4i�K�*s↵���3�f��-`�X3���:.9�o�D���Y��

So it's not downloading at all. Any idea? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm now completely confused as to what you're trying to do. Are you trying to download a file from dropbox? If so you can't do that with ajax on the angular side (not sure how you're getting anything by issuing a post to a get endpoint) Can you give some specifics about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: So on the angular side I sent a post request to the server containing the id of a file to pulldown from dropbox. This works just fine, and I am able to receive the buffer from dropbox on the server. From there, I want to be able to have that file downloaded for the client to use. So basically the user hits a download link which hits dropbox and returns that file to the user. Thoughts?

Comment: Map the code I posted for you to a get route. Encode the file ID into the URL (as part of the path, or as query parameters). Render this URL as a link on your webpage, for example:  `<a href='https://myservice/download?id=file.txt'>Download</a>`

Comment: Okay, getting there. I paste in this:
<a ng-href='http://localhost:8888/download/dropbox/{{file.id}}'>Download</a>
it briefly hits the url, but does not hit the server route, specified as such:
  router.get('/download/dropbox/:id', controller.dropbox.downloadDropBoxFiles);
So controller.dropbox.downloaDropBoxFiles never gets hit.